# Scipy Minimize got different results for different initialization

Tags: python, math, optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize

**Problem Description**

When I run `test()` in the following code, I find that `scipy.optimize.minimize()` got different results for different initialization of the variable to be solved.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import default_rng, Generator
from scipy.optimize import check_grad, minimize, Bounds, LinearConstraint, OptimizeResult

eta=10e-27
k=1e6#to balance the magnitude of the data

# The objective function
def sum_cost(
    f: np.ndarray,
    Adstr: float,
    coef1: np.ndarray,
    coef2: np.ndarray,
) -> float:
    return (k*coef1.dot(f**2) + coef2.dot(1/f) + Adstr)*1e5 #Scale results for easier optimization

# Minimize progress
def cvx1(
    A: np.ndarray,
    ds: np.ndarray,
    ts: np.ndarray,
    tr: np.ndarray,
    Cm: np.ndarray,
    eta: float = 10e-27,
) -> tuple[np.ndarray, OptimizeResult]:
    # parameter definition
    M, N = A.shape
    Adstr = (A/tr @ ds.T).sum()
    coef2 = (A*ts).ravel()
    coef1 = coef2 * eta

    # two constraints for my problem:
    # 1.x0>=0
    # 2.sum(x0,axis=1) <= Cm.reshape((M,)
    #  A      x         Cm
    # (M MN) (MN 1) <= (M 1)
    constraint = LinearConstraint(
        A=np.repeat(np.eye(M), N, axis=1),
        ub=Cm.ravel(),
    )

    # one way to initialize x0
    # Use analytic optimum when it obeys the constraint
    # Use equally divided Cm otherwise.
    optimum = (0.5 / (eta*k)) ** (1 / 3)
    print('optimum',optimum)
    x0 = np.zeros((M, N))
    for m in range(M):
        count = len(np.where(A[m, :] == 1)[0])
        # print(count)
        # print(C_m[0, m])
        x0[m, np.where((A[m, :]) == 1)[0]] = np.minimum(Cm[0, m] / count, optimum)
        x0[m, np.where((A[m, :] == 0))[0]] = 1e-16
    print('initial value for x0:',x0)


    result = minimize(
        fun=sum_cost,
        x0=x0.ravel(), # one way to initialize x0
        # x0=np.ones(M * N),# another way to initialize x0
        args=(Adstr, coef1, coef2),
        bounds=Bounds(lb=0),
        constraints=constraint,
        tol=1e-16,
        options={'maxiter': 1000},
    )
    f = result.x.reshape((M, N))

    print(result)

    if np.allclose(f, x0):
        print('Warning: f == initial; no optimization needed')

    return f, result

def test(M: int=3, N: int=6) -> None:
    rand = default_rng(seed=11)

    #some random parameters for the objective function

    # here just to produce a 0-1 matrix A:
    A = rand.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=(M, N))
    am_current = np.argmax(A, axis=0)
    a_current = np.zeros(A.shape)
    a_current[am_current, np.arange(A.shape[1])] = 1
    A=a_current
    print('A:', A)

    #other parameters
    ds = rand.uniform(500*8, 2_000*8, (1, N))
    ts = rand.uniform(10, 20, (1, N)) * ds
    tr = rand.uniform(50_000, 300_000, (M, N))
    C_m = rand.uniform(5e6, 20e6, (1, M))

    # solve
    x1, result1 = cvx1(A=A, ds=ds, ts=ts, tr=tr, Cm=C_m)
```

I ran the above code twice, once with `x0` customized as above, and again with `x0` all 1's, but I got two different results as follows：

**Results Display**

1.The result for `x0` customized as above

```
initial value for x0: [[1.0000000e-16 3.6840315e+06 1.0000000e-16 1.0000000e-16 1.0000000e-16
  3.6840315e+06]
 [1.0000000e-16 1.0000000e-16 3.6840315e+06 1.0000000e-16 1.0000000e-16
  1.0000000e-16]
 [3.6840315e+06 1.0000000e-16 1.0000000e-16 3.6840315e+06 3.6840315e+06
  1.0000000e-16]]
     fun: 86503.22680146241
     jac: array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0.])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully'
    nfev: 19
     nit: 1
    njev: 1
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([1.0000000e-16, 3.6840315e+06, 1.0000000e-16, 1.0000000e-16,
       1.0000000e-16, 3.6840315e+06, 1.0000000e-16, 1.0000000e-16,
       3.6840315e+06, 1.0000000e-16, 1.0000000e-16, 1.0000000e-16,
       3.6840315e+06, 1.0000000e-16, 1.0000000e-16, 3.6840315e+06,
       3.6840315e+06, 1.0000000e-16])
Warning: f == initial; no optimization needed


============================== 1 passed in 0.18s ==============================
```

2.The result for `x0` all 1's

```
     fun: 87740.20159970068
     jac: array([ 0.        , -0.00097656,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        0.        ,  0.        , -0.00097656,  0.        ,  0.        ,
       -0.00097656, -0.00097656,  0.        ])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully'
    nfev: 8336
     nit: 419
    njev: 417
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([2.57105896e+04, 3.42638038e+06, 1.51942392e+02, 1.51942383e+02,
       1.51942391e+02, 3.46166354e+06, 8.37974281e-01, 8.37972296e-01,
       4.25764167e+06, 8.37974124e-01, 8.37970035e-01, 8.37973655e-01,
       2.77064502e+06, 2.98881278e+06, 4.53859019e+04, 2.86306864e+06,
       3.19190058e+06, 3.59267809e+04])


========================= 1 passed, 1 warning in 0.43s =========================
```

**SOME DOUBTS**

1.As displayed, two different initializations of `x0` give different results.Is there anything wrong with my code and are these results accurate?

2.The first customized `x0` which got the better result need no more optimization( However, it doesn't always got a better result as I tried), is it already the general optimal solution for my objective function?

3.By the way, the first way to initialize `x0` is designed to follow the rule that if `A[m][n]==0,x0[m][n]=0`, but I don't know how to the set this kind of constraint in Scipy?

Thanks in advance and answers to any of these questions are appreciated!

Comment: Note that this is a continuation of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76842195/use-cvxpy-to-solve-convex-problem-but-got-optimal-inaccurate-result

Comment: There is no `scipy.Minimize`; I assume you mean `scipy.optimize.minimize`?

Comment: The behaviour is (completely) normal for non-linear optimizers; in particular for not-so-smooth-and-simple functions (constraints generally add to that non-smoothness). If you start in a (very) different point, you can end up at a different optimum. It is *your* knowledge of the model the and data that can help set the best starting point.

Comment: You can look at a metric, something like a reduced chi-squared, and judge which one is better, and just ignore the other one.

Comment: As to your point 2/ we don't know, and probably you don't know either (even if you have the knowledge of the model and data). It can be very hard (read: impossible) to be sure you have found the *real* optimum (for non-linear functions). The best you can do is provide a metric together with the value, to show how certain you can be about the result.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @9769953 . Yes, it means scipy.optimize.minimize and I have re-edited the question. Sorry that I don't know much about reduced chi-squared, is it for checking whether there is a significant correlation between two categorical variables and how does it apply to my problem? For the last question, the simplified model is just **Find a matrix X that for all m,n , Minimize `sum(coef1*X[m][n]^2+coef2 / X[m][n]))`**, so I guess if it is somehow possible to find the real optimum as shown in the code above(Although I don't know if it's correct or not).

Comment: Can you give some background about the problem? Where does it come from?

Comment: @9769953 ,the background is server resource allocation for users' tasks, where there are `M` servers with a total of `C_m` computing resource and `N` tasks to be allocated to a specified server. And the objective is to find a server resource allocation strategy for every task (`x0`) to minimize the sum of energy consumption and task computing delay. In the code above, the `A[m][n]` represents the mth server is allocated to the nth server. And the constraint is the the total amount of resources allocated by the server cannot exceed the total amount of resources owned by the server `Cm`.

Answer (score 2):

What you're encountering is the [local optimum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_optimum). When you're running the minimizer, it's searching for some optimal solution, where "optimum" is the minimum value in this case. The minimizer you're using is a numerical solver, which basically mean there's a very clever guess-and-check algorithm under the hood. In certain cases, a numerical solver will find *a* solution, but it might not be *the globally best* solution.

For a classic example, imagine you're given the task of finding the tallest mountain in a large mountain range, but you're blindfolded. A reasonable approach would be to take a step forward, and if you feel you're going up an incline, keep going. If you're not going up anymore, test a few different directions around you and see if any of those lead upwards. Eventually, you will reach a peak where all directions around you lead to lower elevations, so you must be at the top! That's great, but how do you know you're at the tallest mountain? Because you're blindfolded, you can't just look around, so really, you can't guarantee you've found the tallest mountain unless you've traversed every square inch of the mountain range -- the time-consuming, brute-force approach. Of course, many mathematicians have come up with better approaches for this problem.

If you want a global minimum, you should look at scipy's [global optimizers](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html#global-optimization). There's multiple options here (including brute force), read up on the documentation, try some out, and see what fits your problem best.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's more clear for me now. However, the simplified objective for my problem is just `Find a matrix X>0 that for all m,n , Minimize sum(coef1*X[m][n]^2+coef2 / X[m][n]))`, and the constraint for X is linear. So I assume it's a convex problem that just has a global solution. However, I'm not sure about it.